# Apple Private Email Relay address - can I use it to request password reset?

Tags: apple-id, user-account

Recently I have used an Apple Private Email Relay address to sign up with an app in order to hide my own email address. Everything went well and I purchased the subscription.

Now I want to use the service on the other platforms as well. But in the web interface they are missing Sign In with Apple.

Since I know my Apple Private Email Relay address I can still sign in with this email, but I need to reset the password to do so.

I already requested password reset for the email address. But how could I access to the private relay email address's inbox.?

The mail has not been received by my default email address associated with my AppleID.

1. Can I request password reset with an Apple Private Email Relay address?
2. How can I view emails sent to Apple Private Email Relay addresses?
3. Are mails sent to the Apple Private Email Relay address rerouted to the email address associated with the AppleID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, in general you can request a password reset using the Apple private relay address. There is a small caveat in that the sender of the the password reset mail must authenticate their emails by registering their outbound email domains and using the Sender Policy Framework (SPF). This is a requirement for app developers / companies that wish to use the private email relay service that comes with "Sign in with Apple".
2. The emails sent to the private relay email address are forwarded on to your real email address and are received just like any other mail.
3. Yes, mails sent to the private relay email address is "rerouted" to the address associated with the AppleID (one of the verified email addresses).

You can read the full details on how this works from Apple here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/communicating_using_the_private_email_relay_service

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer is incorrect. If a user signs up for service A using Signin with Apple *and* opts to hide their email address, there is a unique **@privaterelay.appleid.com** email address that is generated for use by the developer of service A.

If this email address is then provided by the user to service B from a *different* app developer than service A, there is a high likelihood that any emails sent by service B will fail to be delivered to the user.

This is because Apple [uses Sender Policy Framework (SPF) to validate which email domains are allowed to send emails](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/communicating_using_the_private_email_relay_service) to the private relay email address:

> To send emails to users with private email addresses, you must register your outbound emails or email domains and use Sender Policy Framework (SPF) to authenticate your outbound emails. These mechanisms ensure that only you can communicate with your users through this channel, and they prevent spam from getting through.